# Why won't the elements stay in the <div>?

Tags: html

Have a look at this fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VUsVA/1/) for the CSS and HTML view.

The code is:

```
<body>
    <div class="header-bar" id="header-bar">
        <div class="title-bar" id="title-bar">
            <table id="header-table" class="header-table" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="site-title" id="site-title">Site Title</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="site-tagline" id="site-tagline">Site Tagline</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="header-login-bar" id="header-login-bar">
            <div class="header-login-form" id="header-login-form">  
              <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="user-email"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <td><input type="password" name="user-pass"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="header-logged-in" id="header-logged-in">
                Welcome {$user}.
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                <a href="#">Logout</a>
            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content-bar" class="content-bar">
        This is the content part
    </div>
</body>
```

The div with id header-bar must contain all of the elements drawn in this segment, but I cannot understand why, this segment refuses to behave. I am new to design, using more of graphical tools like Dreamweaver with code and design views to make these things, even there the content gets placed all wrong. 
And in the browser, the div with id header-bar does not show any text at all. The div with id header-bar reports a height of 0px in Chrome's Inspect Element.

Comment: I would avoid using tables for layout. They should be used for tabular data. Also resetting your CSS is recommended.

Comment: I think you might want to simple remove the `clear:left` from `.header-login-bar`, and add `clear:both` to `.content-bar` … http://jsfiddle.net/CBroe/VUsVA/4/

Comment: Point noted, I will keep that in mind, right now, I am just learning. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to your header-bar div. When the child elements of any element are floated, they're removed from the normal flow of the document which is why your header-bar div reports a height of zero. Adding `overflow:auto` to the parent div (header-bar) restores the expected behavior.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VUsVA/3/)**